# How to select each module to run in JMeter 3.0

Tags: jmeter

In JMeter 2.11, I use Module Controller to run each module in WorkBench.

[image]

But in JMeter 3.0, I not found module to select in Module Controller.

[image]

When I click Find target element button, it nothing happened.

I want to know how to select each module to run in JMeter 3.0

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure why Module controller doesn't show controllers from Workbench. Moving them to Test Plan might work.

Comment: I try moving to Test Plan but I can't run each module. It run all. I want to know how to select each module to run?

Comment: Once you move to Test Plan, you have to **expand** the Test Plan tree under "Module To Run" section, then **select** the controller you want to run.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to select the controller to run:

1. In module controller, **expand** the Test Plan under "Module To Run", displays all the controllers under the Test Plan.
2. **Click** (or select) the controller you want to run, which highlights the controller to run.

**Note:** Disable controllers if you don't want to run them explicitly. otherwise, the controller will run twice.

[image]